# Comsol simulation for electrochemical impedance spectroscopy

Tags: frequency, simulation, comsol, interdigital

I am new to Comsol and did not know where else to seek help, so posting here.

I am trying to analyse how finger-like interdigital electrodes made of gold can be used to detect concentration of nitrates in drinking water. I am simulating this on Comsol version 5.5 with gold electrodes on a glass (quartz) substrate (model attached). I want to first try and see what the response is like in Air. The frequencies I am looking at is between 10 KHz to 1 MHz at 1V peak-to-peak.

How to go about simulating this to determine impedance change with varying frequencies?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you speak with the makers of the software - this isn't a valid EE design question for this site.

Comment: @andy aka, apologies. I'll delete the questions

Comment: I was told that this topic does not relate to electronics

Comment: if you can make it more EE orientated then maybe it could still be valid but, I think you have to exhaust the possibilities with the [software vendors](https://uk.comsol.com/support) first. I use quickfield and I know it can be an uphill struggle to get even a basic thing working.